# Numpy array to image and the number of channels using PILlow

Tags: python, arrays, image, numpy, python-imaging-library

I want to convert a numpy array into an image and wrote the following code

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

Channels = 5

x = np.random.choice([0,1] , (27,27,Channels), p=[1./3, 2./3])
x *= 255

PIL_im = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(x))
```

It is working perfectly well if `Channels` take 2,3,4 as values and are not working for either 1 or values greater than or equal to 5.

Is there anything wrong in my code? Is it not possible to convert a numpy array into image with more channels?

Comment: You need to use one of Pillow's acceptable modes https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/concepts.html#concept-modes If you want 5 channels, you might consider `tifffile` to write a TIFF.

Comment: x = np.random.choice([0,1, size=(27,27,Channels), p=[1./3, 2./3]) : I believe there is a ] missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Wed Feb  3 19:35:44 2021

@author: Pietro


"""

import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

Channels = 5
# Channels = 1

if Channels < 1:
    Channels = 1

if Channels > 1:
    x = np.random.choice([0,1] , (270,270,Channels), p=[1./3, 2./3])
    
else:
    x = np.random.choice([0,1] , (270,270), p=[1./3, 2./3])
    
# print(x)
print('x[0][0] : ',x[0][0])
print('x shape : ',x.shape)
print('x dim : ',x.ndim)
x *= 255
print('x[0][0] : ',x[0][0])
print('x shape : ',x.shape)
print('x dim : ',x.ndim)

if Channels > 1:
    x = x[:,:,0:4]
    
else:
    x = x


PIL_im = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(x))
    

print('PIL_im size : ', PIL_im.size)
print('PIL_im mode : ', PIL_im.mode)
PIL_im.show()
```

this works for both Channels 1 and >5

I think its related on how pillow (PIL) reads your array if it has more than 4 channels (not sure this is the right name) it cant cope with it.

3 channels are for RGB, 4 for RGBA, 1 monochrome, 2 monochrome with alpha. See here:

[Pillow documentation concepts](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/concepts.html)

if you use:

```
x = np.random.choice([0,1] , (270,270,Channels), p=[1./3, 2./3]).astype(np.uint8)

PIL_im = Image.fromarray(x, mode='RGBA')
```

or :

```
PIL_im = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(x), mode='RGBA')
```

you dont have any error even with more than 5 channels and dont need to slice the array :

```
if Channels > 1:
        x = x[:,:,0:4])
```